# How to assign hours to data that is exceeding the hours?

Tags: python, pandas

considering the following:

```
timeline = pd.date_range(start="2027-01-01",
              end="2061-01-01",
              freq="H")
timeline = timeline[:-1]

df1 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0, 34):
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    df2['value'] = np.random.randint(1, 6, 8900)
    df2['year'] = 2027 + i
    df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Note that, 8900 is always larger than 366 * 24. The objective is to combine the timeline and the df1, such that the first n-rows will be used to fill the timeline. We omit subsequent rows in that year and continue with the next year.

Problem what I am encountering is, is that not all years have the same number of hours, because some are leap years, which are quite troublesome. I was wondering whether there was an effective way to deal with that.

Is there a way to perform the merge, taking into account the intricacies of different hours per year?

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
timeline = timeline.to_frame()
timeline = timeline.rename(columns={(0):'date'})
timeline['tlyear'] = timeline.date.dt.year
timeline = timeline.reset_index(drop=True)
pd.concat([timeline,df1], join='inner', axis=1).drop('tlyear',1)
```

**Complete code**

```
timeline = pd.date_range(start="2027-01-01",
              end="2061-01-01",
              freq="H")
timeline = timeline[:-1]
df1 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0, 34):
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    df2['value'] = np.random.randint(1, 6, 8900)
    df2['year'] = 2027 + i
    df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)

timeline = timeline.to_frame()
timeline = timeline.rename(columns={(0):'date'})
timeline['tlyear'] = timeline.date.dt.year
timeline = timeline.reset_index(drop=True)

pd.concat([timeline,df1], join='inner', axis=1).drop('tlyear',1)
```

**Edit**

```
for i in range(0, 34):
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    df2['value'] = np.random.randint(1, 6, 8900)
    df2['year'] = 2027 + i
    df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)

timeline = timeline.to_frame()
timeline = timeline.rename(columns={(0):'date'})
timeline['year'] = timeline.date.dt.year
timeline = timeline.reset_index(drop=True)

pd.merge_asof(df1, timeline, on='year', direction='nearest')
```

**Output Sample**

```
    date                value   year
0   2027-01-01 00:00:00 5       2027
1   2027-01-01 01:00:00 2       2027
2   2027-01-01 02:00:00 3       2027
3   2027-01-01 03:00:00 4       2027
4   2027-01-01 04:00:00 1       2027
... ... ... ...
298051  2060-12-31 19:00:00 1   2060
298052  2060-12-31 20:00:00 3   2060
298053  2060-12-31 21:00:00 2   2060
298054  2060-12-31 22:00:00 1   2060
298055  2060-12-31 23:00:00 3   2060
```

Comment: I am a bit worried about the order on which the keys are matched. How come if we join on something that as a non-unique key, only the first row of the left table is merged with the first match with the second. In addition, the first that was matched is not going to be used for the second row of the first column. Perhaps I am mistaken, but I cannot find it in the documentation, documenting this behaviour.

Comment: I have edit the code to merge on as of condition. Please check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slightly different approach that come to mind, we can just do the following:

```
df1['Row'] = df1.groupby(['year']).cumcount()
timeline = timeline.to_frame()
timeline = timeline.rename(columns={(0):'date'})
timeline['year'] = timeline.date.dt.year
timeline['Row'] = timeline.groupby(['year']).cumcount()
```

and then merge on them both:

```
result = timeline.merge(df1, on=['year', 'Row'])
```

This will force the row order, I believe.